Swift Charts: RuleMark annotation is invisible when chartScrollableAxes are specified

I’m working on a project that displays the number of steps users have taken in the last 15 days on a chart. I’ve implemented the chart selection behavior introduced in iOS 17, which displays a RuleMark with an annotation for the selected value. However, when I enable a scrollable x-axis, the annotation becomes invisible. See the attached GIF image.
Chart(stepCountRecords) { record in
    BarMark(
        x: .value("Date", record.date, unit: .day),
        y: .value("Count", record.steps)
     )
            
    if let selectedDate {
        RuleMark(x: .value("Selected", selectedDate, unit: .day))
            .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemFill).opacity(0.3))
            .annotation(position: .top, overflowResolution: .init(x: .fit(to: .chart), y: .disabled)) {
                Text(selectedDate.formatted())
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            }
    }
}
/*
 FIXME: Uncomment the following line to trigger the issue in question.
 .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
 */
.chartXSelection(value: $selectedDate)

Is this intentional? Or I’m doing something wrong? It’s worth noting that Apple’s Health app supports scrolling and annotation at the same time.
Here’s a small sample project for your reference.

The problem seems to be that the annotation is shown above the bars, which is clipped by some scroll view that allows scrolling.
You can enable overflowResolution on the y axis,
.annotation(
    position: .top, 
    overflowResolution: .init(
        x: .fit(to: .chart), 
        y: .fit // <---
    )
) { ... }

The annotation will now be placed at the top of the chart, overlaying the bars.
If you don't want the top of the bars to be hidden by the annotation, you can add some top padding instead.
.chartPlotStyle {
    $0.padding(.top, 100)
}


Using chartXSelection with a scrollable chart will often cause the selection gesture to be prioritised over the scrolling gesture. Consider using a SpatialTapGesture to change the selection,
.chartGesture { chartProxy in
    SpatialTapGesture().onEnded { value in
        selectedDate = chartProxy.value(atX: value.location.x, as: Date.self)
    }
}

Here is a complete example:
let data = (0..<30).map {
    Point(x: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400 * Double($0)), y: .random(in: 1...10))
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedDate: Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) { record in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Date", record.x, unit: .day),
                y: .value("Count", record.y)
             )
                    
            if let selectedDate {
                RuleMark(x: .value("Selected", selectedDate, unit: .day))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemFill).opacity(0.3))
                    .annotation(position: .top, overflowResolution: .init(x: .fit(to: .chart), y: .disabled)) {
                        Text(selectedDate.formatted())
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    }
            }
        }
        .chartPlotStyle {
            $0.padding(.top, 100)
        }
        .chartGesture { chartProxy in
            SpatialTapGesture().onEnded { value in
                selectedDate = chartProxy.value(atX: value.location.x, as: Date.self)
            }
        }
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .padding(.vertical, 100)
    }
}

struct Point: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let x: Date
    let y: Int
}


Thank you for your response. Scrolling and selection do work together. You can hold the finger and scroll to select values. Or you can scroll right away to perform actual scrolling on the axis. However, it is still unclear why I cannot position the annotation above the chart when the scrollable axis is enabled. Adding padding to the plot area does not seem to work for me. Moreover, it is likely the wrong solution since that is what overflow resolution is supposed to solve.

I am on iOS 18.1. The entirety of my code is in the attached sample project. According to the documentation, disabling overflow resolution places the annotation as is. However, when the x-axis scrolling is disabled, the annotation appears above the chart. It is puzzling why the annotation is not visible when scrolling is enabled. Hardcoding padding on top is less than ideal.

yes, a mistake on my side. It should be visible now.

Okay, I still cannot reproduce on iOS 18.0, and I don't have iOS 18.1 yet.

This behaviour doesn't contradict what the documentation says. You say position: .top so it is placed "as is" on top of the rule mark, and clipped by the scroll view. You can place a .border around the Chart. Turn off scrolling and you will see that the annotation is outside of the border of the Chart. Turning on the scrolling presumably creates a UIScrollView, and it clips everything outside.
